# how to download apk from playstore using php?

Tags: php

I know this question is asked several times on stackoverflow but there is no answer of this question are available on all those questions...

Hey guys I have this project which needs to download APK file directly from google play store to the PC using a PHP script. I have looked into the python script which is very old and doesn't work now. I see sites like apkpure.com and apk-dl are doing it.

I have used google play link **scraper** Link to **scrape** the application details from google play store. But I can't figure out a way to get the application itself from google play. Can anyone guide me in the right direction for this? I really appreciate it guys. Thanks.

The link scraper that I use only fetch the application information, not the application itself. I also looked into chrome extensions like some of you suggested but they don't hold the answer that I require. Please suggest something else.

Comment: I don't think Google would publish the apps' APK. You could pay one time then download a paid app multiple times... This just does not make sense. Apkpure.com is maybe installing the apps and extracting their APK.

Comment: I am talking about free apps apk @CoderCharmander ... apkpure website is already doing this ... and i also find a solution in node.js but i need it in php

Comment: Well then write what the working node solution does, in PHP accordingly …?

Comment: That's why I am here... I don't know node js